# Knockout Daterangepicker correct moment formatting of date

Tags: knockout.js, momentjs, daterangepicker

I'm trying to use datepicker: https://sensortower.github.io/daterangepicker to have a datepicker with knockout.

All ok, but I also want the custom date fields in the picker itself to be "DD-MM-YYY" (and not as currently "DD/MM/YYYY"

My template definition is:

```html
<input type="text" readonly class="form-control" 
  data-bind=" daterangepicker: dateRange,
              daterangepickerOptions: { 
                maxDate: [moment().add(20,'years')],                                  
                ranges: {
                  'Komende maand': [moment(), moment().add(1,'month')],
                  'Komende week': [moment(), moment().add(1,'week')],
                  'Altijd': 'all-time',
                  'Aangepast:': 'custom'
                },
                periods: ['day'],
                locale: 'nl',
                timeZone: null
              },
              daterangepickerFormat: 'DD-MM-YYYY'," />
```

So in the picker itself it display the current dates to change, but these are still in "en" format.

[image]

Comment: Odd thing is, it does not comes with `format` option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure the `nl` locale setting flag is supported? Replace this by:

```
locale: { inputFormat: 'DD-MM-YYYY' },
```

and the label changes.

### Explanation:

I tried to find out which of the library's source code rendered the label you want to change. Turns out there's a setting being used called `inputFormat`, which should be stored in a `locale` object.

Here's how default settings get applied to this object:

```js
Config.prototype._locale = function(val) {
  return $.extend({
    applyButtonTitle: 'Apply',
    cancelButtonTitle: 'Cancel',
    inputFormat: 'L',
    startLabel: 'Sart',
    endLabel: 'End'
  }, val || {});
};
```

You see the `"L"` value being used as default format, which results in a `DD/MM/YYYY` string. Extending an object with a string (`"nl"` in your template) doesn't make much sense to me, so my guess is that you'll have to create your own settings object. You could compute it from moment.js' locale settings.

*(A codepen in which I threw together a file that has all the libraries you're using and shows that my proposal works: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xEWJKd)*

Comment: Thanks, yes indeed, i thought the local indeed would reference moment's locale